# when to add nodes to cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

What are the symptoms/signs that indicates that the existing cluster nodes are over-capacity and that the cluster would need more nodes to be added? Want to know what are the possible performance symptoms after which more nodes are to be added to the cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the common scenarios you should look after for adding a new node

1. Performance of the cluster is degraded. You are not getting required throughput even after all the tunings.
2. Require more Disk space- Generally you can increase the disk space by adding a new disk but after a limit(2TB generally) it is advised to add a new node.

You have metrices in your hand to identify that your performance is degrading. For example you can use `nodetool tablehistograms` to identify read and write latency for a particular table. If read/write latency is under your required latencies then you are good and if you see your system is getting slower with more traffic, then it is sign that you should add a node to the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on the configuration and your use cases. You may have to take a look at the different metrics from your existing cluster. A few metrics that you should keep an eye on includes.

1. CPU usage
2. Query Latency
3. Memory (Depends how you are using the heap memory)
4. Disk usage

Based on these metrics, you should make a decision whether to scale out the cluster or not.